# Can we share msmessage without develop an imessage extension?

Tags: ios10, imessage

I saw there is `message` property in MFMessageComposeViewController. Can we construct an MSMessage and assign it to MFMessageComposeViewController, then share this message in new iMessage App without developing an extension?   If we can do that, we can share other with a message with images and title, instead of just plain string or attachment before iOS 10.

Comment: I believe that MessageExtension is required to send a special MSMessage for two reasons: to assign correct resource url to message and when it sent to have a mapping message-applicaiton. and also you're not required to fill content of the message extension target.

Answer (score 1):

From what I learn here https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/49922, you need to create an imessage extension target (you don't need to do any develop for the target) , then you can share the msmessage in MFMessageComposeViewController

This is the demo in the link above:

1. Create a brand new Single-View Application
2. In main.storyboard, create a button in the middle of the screen
3. Ctrl-drag "Touch Up Inside" for the button to my ViewController class to create onTouchUp in code (see below)
4. Wrote the code below

   ```
   import UIKit  
   import Messages  
   import MessageUI  

   class ViewController: UIViewController  {  

   override func viewDidLoad() {  
       super.viewDidLoad()    
   }

   override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {  
       super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()  
   }  

   @IBAction func onTouchUp(_ sender: AnyObject) {  
           let composeVC = MFMessageComposeViewController()  
           let msgLayout = MSMessageTemplateLayout()  
           msgLayout.caption = "something here"  
           let message = MSMessage()  
           message.layout = msgLayout  
           composeVC.message = message  

           self.present(composeVC, animated: true, completion: nil)  
       }  
   }
   ```

   5. Create a Target of a MessagesExtension
   6. Run the app on iPhone 6s Plus
   7. See the MSMessage in the MFMessageComposeViewController